# Springboot server in Elastic Beanstalk creates files that I can't see

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Springboot server that is deployed to an Elastic Beanstalk environment in AWS. The basic functionality is this:

```
 1. Upload a file to the server
 2. The server processes file by doing some data manipulation.
 3. Then the file that is created is sent to a user via email.
```

The strange thing is that, the functionality mentioned above **is** working. The output file is sent to my email inbox successfully. **However**, the file cannot be seen when SSHed into the instance. The entire directory that gets created for the data manipulation is just not there. I have looked everywhere.

To test this, I even created a simple function in my Springboot `Controller` like this:

```
    @GetMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<String> dummyMethod() {
        // TODO : remove line below after testing
        new File(directoryToCreate).mkdirs();
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Successful health check. Status: 200 - OK", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

If I use Postman to hit this endpoint, the directory CANNOT be seen via the terminal that I am SSHed into. The program is working so I know that the code is correct in that sense, but its like the files and directories are invisible to me.

Furthermore, if I were to run the server locally (using Windows OR Linux) and hit this endpoint, the directory is successfully created.

**Update:**
I found where the app lives in the environment at `/var/app`. But my folders and files are still not there, only the source code files, ect are there. The files that my server is supposed to be creating are still missing. I can even print out the absolute path to the file after creating it, but that file still doesn't exist. Here is an example:

```
            Files.copy(source, dest);
            logger.info("Successfully copied file to: {}", dest.getAbsolutePath());
```

will print...

`Successfully copied file to: /tmp/TESTING/Test-Results/GVA_output_2021-12-13 12.32.58/results_map_GVA.csv`

That path DOES NOT exist in my server, but I CAN send it to me via email from the server code after being processed. But if I SSH into the instance and go to that path, nothing is there.

If I use the command: `find . -name "GVA*"` (to search for the file I am looking for) then it prints this:

```
./var/lib/docker/overlay2/fbf04e23e39d61896a1c935748a63f2d3836487d9b166bae490764c30b8870ae/diff/tmp/TESTING/Test-Results/GVA_output_2021-12-09 18.15.59
./var/lib/docker/overlay2/fbf04e23e39d61896a1c935748a63f2d3836487d9b166bae490764c30b8870ae/diff/tmp/TESTING/Test-Results/GVA_output_2021-12-13 12.26.34
./var/lib/docker/overlay2/fbf04e23e39d61896a1c935748a63f2d3836487d9b166bae490764c30b8870ae/diff/tmp/TESTING/Test-Results/GVA_output_2021-12-13 12.32.58
./var/lib/docker/overlay2/fbf04e23e39d61896a1c935748a63f2d3836487d9b166bae490764c30b8870ae/merged/tmp/TESTING/Test-Results/GVA_output_2021-12-09 18.15.59
./var/lib/docker/overlay2/fbf04e23e39d61896a1c935748a63f2d3836487d9b166bae490764c30b8870ae/merged/tmp/TESTING/Test-Results/GVA_output_2021-12-13 12.26.34
./var/lib/docker/overlay2/fbf04e23e39d61896a1c935748a63f2d3836487d9b166bae490764c30b8870ae/merged/tmp/TESTING/Test-Results/GVA_output_2021-12-13 12.32.58
```

But this looks like it is keeping track of differences between versions of files since I see `diff` and `merged` in the file path. I just want to find where that file is actually residing.

Comment: The application lives in `/var/app`. Did you check there? Also where do you expect the directory to be created? Where it is done on your local server on linux?

Comment: I did find the app located in `/var/app` but the files & folders that get created from the server are not there. I am using absolute paths, even if I print the absolute path of the working directory, it will say `Working directory is /tmp/TESTING`. Meaning that inside `TESTING` is where my files should be but the folder `TESTING` doesn't even exist somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to store an uploaded file somewhere from a Spring BOOT app, look at using an Amazon S3 bucket as opposed to writing the file to a folder on the server. For example, assume you are working with a Photo app and the photos can be uploaded via the Spring BOOT app. Instead of placing this in a directory on the server, use the Amazon S3 Java API to store the file in an Amazon S3 bucket.

Here is an example of using a Spring BOOT app and handling uploaded files by placing them in a bucket.

[Creating a dynamic web application that analyzes photos using the AWS SDK for Java](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/usecases/creating_photo_analyzer_app)

This example app also shows you how to use the SES API to send data (a report in this example) to a user via email.